# How to calculate server time from client time

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have webpage with lots of dynamic content and that gets loaded only once with server time.

The user stays on webpage very long time, does lot of time dependent activities.
These activities I need to log in browser **localstorage** with datetime(time) of server.

So how do I calculate or find or get the server time from relative client time without making new request to the server.

Any suggestions appreciated and thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used following Approach to get server time from client time

1. Take the difference of client time and server time when page loads for the 1st time.

   ```
   var TIMEDIFF = new Date().getTime()-parseInt('<%= Time.now.to_i%>')*1000;
   ```
2. Later do following operation to get server time without making request to server from client time.

   ```
   new Date().getTime()-TIMEDIFF
   ```

Answer (score 0):

This is absolutely impossible. If something happens on the client side, and you don't make a request to the server there is no way for the server to know about it.

However, if you simply mean that you do not want the page to reload, you can use AJAX to send asynchronous (background) requests to the server, without the user knowing about it.

https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

You can get the current time from `Time.now` or `Time.new`. The time object components can be used on the client side Javascript to save the time on client system.

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby -w

time = Time.new
# time = Time.now # => Also can be used
puts time.strftime("%Y,%m,%d,%H,%M,%S,%2N") # => "2014,03,06,02,41,29,85"
```

In JS, date object can be initialized in different ways such as:

1. `new Date(milliseconds) //milliseconds since 1970/01/01`
2. `new Date(dateString)`
3. `new Date(year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds)`

The third method can be used here. Use the following code in the rails template file.

```
var currentDate = new Date(<%= Time.now.strftime('%Y,%m,%d,%H,%M,%S,%2N') %>);
alert(currentDate.toString());
```